# The named parameter 'manager' isn't defined for Shortcuts

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working with a ready-made application in which bugs need to be fixed. I have this problem: The named parameter 'manager' isn't defined. How can it be solved?

```js
body: Shortcuts(
manager: LoggingShortcutManager(),
shortcuts: < LogicalKeySet, Intent > {
  LogicalKeySet(
    LogicalKeyboardKey.control,
    LogicalKeyboardKey.keyC
  ): const CtrlIntent(),
},
...
)),


class LoggingShortcutManager extends ShortcutManager {
  @override
  KeyEventResult handleKeypress(BuildContext context, RawKeyEvent event) {
    final KeyEventResult result = super.handleKeypress(context, event);
    if (result == KeyEventResult.handled) {
      print('Handled shortcut $event in $context');
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: it is working, can you try `flutter clean` and rebuild the app. if fails `flutter upgrade`

Comment: I tried flutter clean and flutter pub get but the error still remains

Comment: Wha is the name of your `LoggingShortcutManager` file

Comment: The LoggingShortcutManager is in the same file as the Shortcuts.

Comment: Try checking the source code if you've changed some, also the import section if it is coming from different package